# How to set timer on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce

I need to set timer on Visualforce page, and after time interval a button will be displayed, can we do that in VF page ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can easily do this task using javascript. Initially hide the button and after the timer display the button using [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```
<script>
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
</script>
```

Instead of this button display the button.